# Add image to table not working properly using iTextSharp C#

Tags: c#, image, itext, row

I have to create a PDF with 1 row 3 columns with contents chosen by the user

In column 1 I have to put picture 1
In column 2 I have to put a writing
In column 3 I have to put picture 2

For example this might be pic1 572x762
[image]

and this picture 2 1024x768
[image]

Now what I want is that the table stays always with the same height.

The code is the following

```
float fRow1Height = 30;

string strImageFile1 =...
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 25, 50, 25 });
PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell();
if (strImageFile1.IsCorrectPath() && File.Exists(strImageFile1))
{
    string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strImageFile1).TrimAndUpper();
    if (strExtension == ".JPEG" || strExtension == ".JPG" || strExtension == ".PNG" || strExtension == ".BMP")
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(strImageFile1);
                    c1 = new PdfPCell(pic) { FixedHeight = fRow1Height, HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER };
    }
}
table.AddCell(c1);
```

---

```
String strArialBlack = @"C:\Windows\Fonts\ariblk.ttf";
BaseFont bfArialBlack;
bfArialBlack = BaseFont.CreateFont(strArialBlack, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, false);
var fntArialBlack = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfArialBlack, 16);
string strMR = Measuring Report";
var phrMR = new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(strMR, fntArialBlack);
```

---

```
PdfPCell c2 = new PdfPCell(phrMR) { HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER, VerticalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, };
table.AddCell(c2);
```

---

```
string strImageFile2 = ...
PdfPCell c3 = new PdfPCell();
if (strImageFile2.IsCorrectPath() && File.Exists(strImageFile2))
{
    string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strImageFile2).TrimAndUpper();
    if (strExtension == ".JPEG" || strExtension == ".JPG" || strExtension == ".PNG" || strExtension == ".BMP")
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(strImageFile2);
        c3 = new PdfPCell(pic) { FixedHeight = fRow1Height, HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER };
    }
}
table.AddCell(c3);

table.WidthPercentage = 100;

doc.Add(table);
```

The result is correct if I put the first line of the code float fRow1Height = 30;

[image]

while if I change it to fRow1Height = 50;
picture 1 disappears with no explicit reason

[image]

Can anyone explain me how to fix this?

Comment: Please [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136168/set-cell-height-in-pdf-table-created-with-itextsharp) solution, it might help you.